# Ruby: rspec not catching exceptions?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I'm having trouble grasping how rspec handles exceptions. In this case, I'd like to ensure the exception is properly caught and returned in a formatted message.

Consider the following:

```rb
class Sample

  def calculate(x, y)
    begin
      add(x,y)
    rescue Exception => e
      return "Exception occured: #{e}"
    end
  end
  
  def add(x, y)
    x + y
  end
end
```

With a spec like so:

```rb
describe "sample" do
  it "adds numbers" do
    test = Sample.new

    allow(test)
      .to receive(:calculate)
      .with(1, 2) { Exception.new('foo') }

    expect(test.calculate(1,2)). to eq 'Exception occurred: foo'
  end
end
```

I would expect the exception to be properly caught by rspec as it is by the method `calculate` itself, however, I receive the following when executing the spec:

```sh
Failures:

  1) sample adds numbers
     Failure/Error: expect(test.calculate(1,2)). to eq 'Exception occurred: foo'
     
       expected: "Exception occurred: foo"
            got: #<Exception: foo>
     
       (compared using ==)
     
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -"Exception occurred: foo"
       +#<Exception: foo>
```

But when testing the rescue via irb, it's properly handled:

```sh
irb(main):001:0> test = Sample.new()
=> #<Sample:0x000055d0f864db50>
irb(main):002:0> test.calculate("i", 2)
=> "Exception occured: no implicit conversion of Integer into String"
irb(main):003:0>
```

I'm very new to rspec so any feedback is welcome :D

Comment: allow(test)
      .to receive(:add)
      .with(1, 2)
      .and_raise(Exception.new('foo'))

Comment: @LamPhan this results in the same output from rspec

Comment: please check for sure that you stub `:add` method to raise an error ( notice `and_raise`), I checked on my side and it work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Uou need to stub `add` method instead of `calculate` and instead of returning the Exception you need to raise the Exception.

```
describe "sample" do
  it "adds numbers" do
    test = Sample.new

    allow(test)
      .to receive(:add)
      .with(1, 2).and_raise(Exception.new('foo'))

    expect(test.calculate(1,2)). to eq 'Exception occurred: foo'
  end
end
```

Comment: Hm, this results in the same error though? 

```ruby
     Failure/Error: expect(test.calculate(1,2)). to eq 'Exception occurred: foo'
     
       expected: "Exception occurred: foo"
            got: #<Exception: foo>
     
       (compared using ==)
```

Comment: @no_onespecial I have updated the answer. could you please check now?

Comment: also there is typo in `calculate` method for `occured` change it to `occurred`